# Line plot with arrows

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I have a line graph that I want to plot using arrows instead of lines. That is, the line between successive pairs of points should be an arrow going from the first point to the second point.

I know of the `arrow` function, but that only seems to do individual arrows. Before I work out a way to try and use this to do a whole plot, is there a nicer way to do it?

Comment: You could superpose a [quiver plot](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver) on your line plot.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can do this with [quiver](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver), but it's a little tricky to get the keyword arguments right.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.figure()
plt.quiver(x[:-1], y[:-1], x[1:]-x[:-1], y[1:]-y[:-1], scale_units='xy', angles='xy', scale=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you too need to modify List/Array slices with commas to use quiver in this way, I found this reminder handy: http://structure.usc.edu/numarray/node26.html

Comment: Does anyone figure out how to add the label for each point

Comment: @JasonLiLy Yes, that would be very useful to me, too. Anyone?