# Adding arrows to parametric plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm doing simulations where multiple variables vary in time. Occasionally, it is useful to plot variables not against the time axis (x(t) versus t) but against each other (x(t) versus y(t)).
In these cases, it'd be nice if I could add some sort of arrows (overlaid on the curve) indicating the direction of time flow.

My question: does anybody know of an easy or built-in method to do this, or should I hack something together myself?

Comment: Not looking to plot a vector field here. I have a curve (more of a loop really) that represents the different points in parameter space reached during a simulation. What I'm looking for is a way to overlay a few arrows on that curve showing what direction the simulation was heading in.

Comment: Right - I was hasty in reading your question. I still think you can [hack something together with `quiver`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519467/line-plot-with-arrows-in-matplotlib), plotting over your existing curve and using say only the first two and/or last two points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (from the matplotlib cookbook http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Arrows):

```
from pylab import *
from numarray import *

x = arange(10)
y = x

# Plot junk and then a filled region
plot(x, y)

# Now lets make an arrow object
arr = Arrow(2, 2, 1, 1, edgecolor='white')

# Get the subplot that we are currently working on
ax = gca()

# Now add the arrow
ax.add_patch(arr)

# We should be able to make modifications to the arrow.
# Lets make it green.
arr.set_facecolor('g')
```

[image]