# Chevron linestyle in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, linestyle

Is it possible to make a dashed linestyle using more complicated shapes in matplotlib (or any other python plotting library)? It's easy to make a linestyle with different spacings and combinations of dots and dashes, but I'm after something like this:

[image]

I can envision a way of doing it by writing a function from scratch to take a custom chevron marker style and working out the angle to display it at and the correct spacing etc. However that seems like an overly complicated way to address the problem that will easily break down for things like different specified line widths.

Comment: Please post the code you are trying in the question

Comment: There is no built-in way to accomplish this in matplotlib. The difficulty is to set the correct shape size in screen coordinates for a path in data coordinates. In case you are interested in showing the direction of a curve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619545/how-to-plot-a-directed-line-in-matplotlib) may be of help.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I thought that might be the case unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion, but I specifically need the style mentioned in the OP - I think I'll just have to see what I can accomplish with some awful hacky solution.

Comment: @DaFois I haven't got any code to show. I know how to achieve a hacky solution that I should be able to tailor to suit my specific need, but I'm after a general "proper" solution. I haven't got a clue where to even start for that.

Comment: What would be the desired outcome if the line wasn't straight but curved? It seems the spacing between markers would then need to depend not only on the markersize but also on the curvature?

Answer (score 1):

If you find a better latex symbol, you could do something like this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\boldmath', r'\usepackage{amsmath}', r'\usepackage{amssymb}', r'\usepackage{fontawesome}']
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot('111')
ax.plot(np.linspace(0,10,10),np.repeat(10,10),marker='$>$',ls='',ms=50,mew=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Look at the symbols in the [fontawesome](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome/doc/fontawesome.pdf) latex package, it might have something closer to what you're wanting. Then you can substitute the marker `marker='$>$'` for another latex symbol.