# Python plotting float lists with directional arrows

Tags: python, matplotlib

After inspiring from this answer in [Line plot with arrows in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519467/line-plot-with-arrows-in-matplotlib) , I tried this but not working.

My code:

```
x = [34.9, 34.9, 34.9, 34.9, 35.7, 34.9, 34.9, 34.1, 34.1, 34.9]
y = [19.544, 19.544, 16.752, 17.45, 17.85, 17.45, 18.846, 17.05, 15.686, 18.846] 

plt.figure()
plt.quiver(x[:-1], y[:-1], x[1:]-x[:-1], y[1:]-y[:-1], scale_units='xy', angles='xy', scale=1)
plt.show()
```

Present output:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use usual lists. This will work

```
x = np.array([34.9, 34.9, 34.9, 34.9, 35.7, 34.9, 34.9, 34.1, 34.1, 34.9])
y = np.array([19.544, 19.544, 16.752, 17.45, 17.85, 17.45, 18.846, 17.05, 15.686, 18.846])

plt.figure()
plt.quiver(x[:-1], y[:-1], x[1:]-x[:-1], y[1:]-y[:-1], scale_units='xy', angles='xy', scale=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am plotting two dataframe columns. Looks like I have to convert them to array as well.