# How to get Python quiver end arrow head EXACLY at end point

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I cannot find a clear answer on how to use quiver to plot a 2D vector starting at a point, e.g., v1 and ending at v2, with the arrow head EXACLTY stopping at v2 and no strange scaling or other.

I cannot understand why this is not the default behavior.

Simply plotting like:

```
plt.quiver(v1[1],v1[0],v2[1],-v2[0],color=['r','g','b'])
```

does not work. It applies a scaling that I do not want. Please note that I am plotting these vectors over an image, which is why 0 and 1 indexes are swapped and the minus sign is present, because I don't use the  quiver's own axis system.

Comment: Well, a quiver plot is generally used to convey data that contains magnitude and direction at each point. It sounds like you want https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html ?

Comment: Yes I can imagine for vector fields, but anyway there should be a simple option e.g. 'exact' or whatever ... but I tried your arrow and strangely I still get it out of the picture (too long) I did simply: plt.arrow(v1[1],v1[0],v2[1],v2[0])

Comment: Did you read the documentation linked above?

Comment: Here's [an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519467/line-plot-with-arrows-in-matplotlib/7543518#7543518) of mine, which I think will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, I finally managed to do it ... was a bit tired

Answer (score 0):

1. Use arrow instead of quiver
2. Set length_includes_head to True
   length_includes_head: bool (default: False)
   True if head is to be counted in calculating the length.

`self.ax.arrow(0, 0, vector.x, vector.y, head_width=0.15, head_length=0.1, length_includes_head=True,**kwargs)`