# The rotation of a matplotlib marker on a 2D canvas is not rotating properly. How do I correctly rotate a matplotlib marker by it's center?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, rotation, matlab-figure

currently I am having trouble properly rotating a marker using the plot function on matplotlib. I am using the marker as an arrow and would like the line it is on to go through the tip of the arrow. Currently this works for any rotation that is a multiple of 90 degrees.

The current code I have is this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle
from math import sqrt, atan, pi

point_1 = [1,1]
point_2 = [1,2]
mid_point = ((point_1[0] + point_2[0]) / 2, (point_1[1] + point_2[1]) / 2)
plt.plot(mid_point[0], mid_point[1], marker=(3, 0, 0), markersize=20, linestyle='None')
plt.plot([point_1[0], point_2[0]], [point_1[1], point_2[1]], linewidth=1, linestyle='-')

point_1 = [1,1]
point_2 = [2,2]
mid_point = ((point_1[0] + point_2[0]) / 2, (point_1[1] + point_2[1]) / 2)
plt.plot(mid_point[0], mid_point[1], marker=(3, 0, -45), markersize=20, linestyle='None')
plt.plot([point_1[0], point_2[0]], [point_1[1], point_2[1]], linewidth=1, linestyle='-')

point_1 = [2,2]
point_2 = [3,2]
mid_point = ((point_1[0] + point_2[0]) / 2, (point_1[1] + point_2[1]) / 2)
plt.plot(mid_point[0], mid_point[1], marker=(3, 0, -90), markersize=20, linestyle='None')
plt.plot([point_1[0], point_2[0]], [point_1[1], point_2[1]], linewidth=1, linestyle='-')



plt.xlim([0,4])
plt.ylim([0,4])

plt.show()
```

which produces the following figure.

[image]

As you can see, the arrow in the middle should be centered at the line it is on at 45 degrees but it is not. I have also tested this at multiple angles and it seems that the closer the rotation gets to 45 degrees, the more the arrow deviates from the line. This the same for all angles in between multiples of 90 degrees.

Is there a way to fix this. I believe this is due to the center of rotation of the markers, but I am not sure how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a line with the slope of `1` is not generally at a 45 degree angle.  If you make the axes the same range and square, then the angles match:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
```

[image]

You can also set the angle based on the angle of the plotted line (when the axes aren't square), but you need to decide what you want to hold constant.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how would I find the angle of the plotted line? Is there a function I can use to get the current figsize?

Comment: @Trenton: It's possible to know the axes lengths and the figure size and set the angle to the correct value for a preset slope, but then that wouldn't hold if you resize the plot, or maybe when printed, eg, for publication. It would be better to take this information where you now know that the real problem is, and think through what you really need. Maybe [arrow](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html#matplotlib.pyplot.arrow), or even draw your own from lines; both of which would be better than digging in on using a marker, imho.

Comment: @Trenton: Overall I'd suggest: 1) understanding the issues here (which are that plots have multiple coordinate systems running simultaneously and that generally the x and y axes are assumed to scale independently so angles aren't represented well); and 2) I'm assuming some factors of the plot were done out of convenience, so decide what you need in your plot from scratch (if you used arrows, would you rather they all be the same length or scale with the length of the line; do you want them at the beginning, middle, or end of the line; etc) and ask a new question based on these details.

Comment: For example, [this type of line plot with arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519467/line-plot-with-arrows-in-matplotlib) is very easy, and looks good, imho, and is easier to view because the viewer doesn't have to do a double-take to remap a triangle marker by pretending it's a direction arrow.  I'd believe you if you said, "no, you just want exactly what you've show in your plot", but typically, if someone misunderstands a basic principle of the software, they end up wanting something different in the end.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I have decided to use arrows